# Windows Server 2008 Stnd - Wins Issue Possibly?

Tags: windows-server-2008, netbios, wins

Currently we have a freshly setup Windows Server 2008 server acting as DNS and AD,Print and File server.

I setup VPN and routing services and was able to successfully connect through VPN however I can't resolve any host using NETBios names.  Only IP addresses. Sounds like I need to add a role for WINS but since this is a LIVE environment I'm a little hesitant about adding and removing additions to the box.

What would I need to do to resolve this issue?

Comment: is a WINS role even an option for Win2k8? (honest question -- I don't have any win2k8 but I thought I'd heard it had gone away)

Comment: Yopu can install WINS on W2K8, but it's listed as a feature, not a role.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct... in order to resolve NetBIOS, you would need to enable the WINS feature.  However, I since WINS is on its way out, and you have Windows Server 2008, I would take a look at the new DNS GlobalNames Zones feature which allows you to resolve single-lable names while still using DNS.

Overview here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2008.01.cableguy.aspx (it's the last section of the article)

In-depth discussion here: 

 - [DNS Server GlobalNames Zone Deployment](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=1c6b31cd-3dd9-4c3f-8acd-3201a57194f1&displaylang=en)

 - [Deploying a GlobalNames Zone](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731744(classic).aspx)